# Javascript for loop not getting length inside another for loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I am trying to loop through my json value obtain from my server which is like this:

```
  [
    {
    below_min: [
    {
    y: 0,
    label: "Bhagalpur",
    color: "Red"
    },
    {
    y: 0,
    label: "Gopalganj",
    color: "Red"
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    min: [
    {
    y: 0.2,
    label: "Samastipur",
    color: "Orange"
    },
    {
    y: 0.3,
    label: "Saran",
    color: "Orange"
    }
    }
    ]
    }
]
```

I am using this loop code to get the value of my below_min array:

```
  for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
        const element = res[index];
        console.log(element.below_min);  
        // const u = element.below_min

        for (let index = 0; index < element.below_min.length; index++) {
            const h = element.below_min[index];

        }

    }
```

but I am getting error:

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I have tried few things such as when I am trying to see what is this below_min as type of I am seeing this as an object. My question is what is wrong with my code.

Comment: you should rename your nested loop `let index = 0;` to something else.

Comment: it is not working I am getting same error.

Comment: your json format is wrong check it again

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli  What's JSON got to do with this. ?   To me it looks like he has an invalid Javacript Object literal..

Comment: http://bihar.aaupf.org/rainfalls/test?views=Map%20View&rain_fall_type=Winter%20Rain&year=2016 . this is my json data. You can see it live. I am trying to loop through this

Comment: because he said it's the result from server

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli  That's obviously now parsed, and is no longer JSON.

Comment: You data containes a lot objects without `below_min` which means it's undefined

Comment: alright Keith, you are right and I am wrong, be happy

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli  You too.. , :)  Ps.  You have the correct answer,  post an answer for the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript Object literal has syntax issue. so i tried to correct it.

You can try the following code and get the idea about getting `below_min` correctly:

```js
const res =  [
    {
        below_min: [
            {
                y: 0,
                label: "Bhagalpur",
                color: "Red"
            },
            {
                y: 0,
                label: "Gopalganj",
                color: "Red"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        min: [
            {
                y: 0.2,
                label: "Samastipur",
                color: "Orange"
            },
            {
                y: 0.3,
                label: "Saran",
                color: "Orange"
            }
        ]
    }
];

for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
    const element = res[index];
    
    if(element.below_min){
        for (let minIndex = 0; minIndex < element.below_min.length; minIndex++) {
            const h = element.below_min[minIndex];
            console.log(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains a lot of elements that doesn't have `below_min` property and when you want to reach the property it will return `undefined`.